# Retrieve SNMP data in C#

Tags: c#, snmp

I need to write a program that get the *total number of printed pages* for my company network printer monthly and generate a `report`. After doing research I found out that it can be done with `SNMP`. But I'm not sure how to retrieve the SNMP data in `C#`. My model printer is **HP laserjet**. Please advise.

Comment: How did you find out it can be done with SNMP?

Comment: I have created the program and it able to retrieve the printer information from SNMP using PJL.

Comment: IETF only defined a general MIB document, http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3805, but what you are looking for might not be included. Thus, contacting the vendor (aka HP) is always your first option.